# How to get the path of a file in text

Tags: batch-file

I have a variable

```
set i = %1
```

%1 is d:\work\temp_h.txt

I want to get a path "d:\work". If I use the below code I can get the name of path

```
%%~nxi
```

%%~nxi= temp_h.txt. How can I get the path of i ? ( like that d:\work )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
%~I expands %I removing any surrounding quotes (")
%~fI    expands %I to a fully qualified path name
%~dI    expands %I to a drive letter only
%~pI    expands %I to a path only
%~nI    expands %I to a file name only
%~xI    expands %I to a file extension only
%~sI    expanded path contains short names only
%~aI    expands %I to file attributes of file
%~tI    expands %I to date/time of file
```

These are some of the modifiers that can be used. In your case you can use  %~dp1

Answer (score 1):

```
set subdir=%~dp1
echo %subdir%
```

This will give you the directory part of whatever is there in `%1` - first command line argument.